# Position Background Image

Tags: c#, image, button, visual-studio-2013, background-image

I was wondering if there is any possible way to position a background image on a button in C# windows forms? I am using Visual Studio 2013, and  I noticed that you can use the `BackgroundImageLayout` but that is very limited. I would like to move the background image around by pixel position, or relative to the button. Kind of like this:

[image]

I have been on google for a while now with no luck. If anyone could point me in the right direction, or show my an article to read it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using WPF? If so this is trivial.

Comment: Sorry, I am using windows forms. I updated the question to show that.

Comment: Do you mean _move the background image around_ as in _animation_ or do you simply want to put it where it belongs? I guess the answer to both will be to create it as you need it, in advance for the latter or dynamically for the former goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Paint` event (or subclass `Button` to override `OnPaint`) to draw the image yourself:

```
private void myButton_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(myImage, myButton.ClientRectangle);
}
```

You could then use the `TextAlign` and `Padding` properties to control the location of the text.

Note that you should not assign the image to the `Button`'s `Image` or `BackgroundImage` properties, otherwise .NET will also render the image.